# pageshow eventlistener not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have this div in a file called clockIn.html

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="hrsWorked">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
            <h1>Hours Worked</h1>
              <a href="clockIn.html" id="exitBtn">Back</a>

        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="hrsWorkedDiv">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have this eventListener in clockIn.js which is included at the top of clockIn.html

```
$(document).on("#hrsWorked", "pageshow", function()
    {
        alert('here 1');
        displayHrsWorked(localStorage.getItem('carerID'));
    });
```

And I am not getting the alert. What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to this and am picking up someone else's code. Jquery mobile version: 'js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js' and cordova version: 'js/cordova-2.6.0.js'

Comment: `"pageshow", ".selector", function` event and then selector.

Answer (score 0):

The onpageshow event is similar to the onload event, except that it occurs after the onload event when the page first loads. Also, the onpageshow event occurs every time the page is loaded, whereas the onload event does not occur when the page is loaded from the cache. 
[Reference to w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onpageshow.asp)

Comment: I must be missing the point, but i don't understand why I am not getting the alert when i navigate to that page in my app or on the browser?